# Marking an internal class @objc?

Tags: objective-c, swift, class, nsobject

I'm trying to compile some swift code here

```
 import Foundation

 let BaseSocketErrorDomain = "com.thing.base_socket";

 @objc internal protocol GATToIPBaseSocketDelegate {
     @objc optional func txReady(_: GATToIPBaseSocket)
     @objc optional func rxData(_: GATToIPBaseSocket, data:Data) -> Bool
     @objc optional func didConnect(_: GATToIPBaseSocket)
     @objc optional func didDisconnect(_: GATToIPBaseSocket, error: Error?)
 }

 @objc internal class GATToIPBaseSocket: NSObject {
     enum SocketError: Error {
         case notConnected
         case noSpaceAvailable
         case sendError
     }

     weak var delegate: GATToIPBaseSocketDelegate?
     private(set) var isConnected: Bool = false

     func openConnection() {
         // nothing yet
     }

 }
```

Which results in the following error

```
/home/pi/ReWork/GATToIP/GATToIP/BaseSocket.swift:20:2: error: only classes that inherit from NSObject can be declared @objc
@objc internal class GATToIPBaseSocket: NSObject {
~^~~~~
```

However, the class is very obviously marked `@objc` and inherits from `NSObject`. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?